# Symfony2, switch to HTTPS after authentication

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I want to force user to use HTTPS instead of HTTP but only after authentication. The only option I've found is forcing HTTPS on per controller/method basis. Anonymous users should only use HTTP.

How to set force-HTTPS only for authenticated users and force NOT to use HTTPS for unauthenticated users in all controllers in my bundle?

Again - this isn't about disabling HTTPS for authorisation page.

I want to use all the same controllers for authenticated and unauthenticated users but force those logged in to use HTTPS, and those who aren't to use HTTP. Basically add requirement for HTTPS for ALL controllers when the user is authenticated.

This question is Symfony 2 specific. I want to do it using Symfony mechanisms. I know how to detect this thing, but it will break Twig links. Symfony can automatically switch to HTTPS, I just want to know how to do it on per-user role basis, not per controller basis.

Comment: Not using HTTPS for authentication is a BAD decision. It means the data sent/received is plain text, and anyone with access to any machine in the route between the client and your server would be able to read the packets and gather the credentials (user, pass, cookie, etc). Is there a special reason for not using SSL for authentication?

Comment: @jweyrich This is not the question. I want user to use https for all subsequent pages after authorization (which is external btw) and disable https for unauthorized users.

Comment: Both answers in that linked duplicate show PHP Code to detect whether the current request is using SSL and how to redirect to SSL if not. The code is page agnostic. All you have to do is add an if block checking whether a user is authenticated or not.

Comment: In every controller? This question is Symfony 2 specific. I want to do it using Symfony mechanisms. I know how to detect this thing, but it will break Twig links. Symfony can automatically switch to HTTPS, I just want to know how to do it on per-user role basis, not per controller basis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One would think the access controller would do this for us:

```
access_control:
    - { role: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
    - { role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
```

But, no...  I think this would be a very nice feature though.

In that case, we can hack something together with a request listener using kernel events:

```
namespace YourBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class RequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // force ssl based on authentication
        if ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            if (!$request->isSecure()) {
                $request->server->set('HTTPS', true);
                $request->server->set('SERVER_PORT', 443);
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getUri()));
            } 
        } else {
            if ($request->isSecure()) {
                $request->server->set('HTTPS', false);
                $request->server->set('SERVER_PORT', 80);
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getUri()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Define your listener in config.yml under services:

```
myapp.request.listener:
    class: MyApp\MyBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

See [Symfony Internals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#internal-requests) for details on events and the like.

Comment: You can check our bundle that allows automated behaviors like forcing ssl for logged in users, without giving a 403 if they access the site without https: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSecurityBundle

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 2.0.11 I get a redirection error.
To solve this I've commented out the following lines in the listener.

```
class RequestListener {
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // force ssl based on authentication
        if     ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            if (!$request->isSecure()) {
                $request->server->set('HTTPS', true);
                $request->server->set('SERVER_PORT', 443);
                // $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getUri()));
            } 
        } else {
            if ($request->isSecure()) {
                $request->server->set('HTTPS', false);
                $request->server->set('SERVER_PORT', 80);
                // $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getUri()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```